# npm не работает

Tags: node.js

у меня проблема с npm. Он ничего не устанавливает, но в cmd он говорит, что npm не является внешней или внутренней командой, я прикрепил то что он пишет мне в коде Visual Studio, вы можете мне помочь

PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\musicbot> npm install ffmpeg

Usage: npm

where is one of: access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit, clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config, create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor, edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init, install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln, login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix, profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root, run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star, stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un, uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view, whoami

npm -h quick help on npm -l display full usage info npm help search for help on npm help npm involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file: C:\Users\User.npmrc or on the command line via: npm --key value Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

Comment: Хм, а почему в выводе не говорится о том, что npm не является командой? У Вас имеется файл package.json?

Comment: Под администратором зашел в систему ? если нет перелогинься

Comment: Жека Диулин package.json у меня имеется. Я имею ввиду что в командной строке пишет что npm не является внешней или внутренней командой